# Como editar relógio em javascript para mudar a cor do time em horários específicos

Tags: javascript

Ola gostaria de saber como posso editar o código abaixo para que funcione da seguinte forma necessito que ao dar 12 AM o time do relógio fique com os números verdes das 12 AM ate as 6:45 AM  depois desse horário a cor do time fique e vermelho ate dar novamente o período programado para o time ficar com a cor verde novamente.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer2 ,1000);
function myTimer2() {
    var d = new Date(), displayDate;
   if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
      displayDate = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
   } else {
      displayDate = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', {timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo'});
   }
      document.getElementById("relogio").innerHTML = displayDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que isto vai funcionar.

```
setInterval(myTimer2, 1000);

const colorChangeHoursBegin = 0;
const colorChangeHoursEnd = 6;

const colorChangeMinutesBegin = 0;
const colorChangeMinutesEnd = 45;

function myTimer2() {
  let d = new Date(), displayDate;
  if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
    displayDate = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
  } else {
    displayDate = d.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo' });
  }

  let colorChangeBegin = new Date();
  colorChangeBegin.setHours(colorChangeHoursBegin, colorChangeMinutesBegin);

  let colorChangeEnd = new Date();
  colorChangeEnd.setHours(colorChangeHoursEnd, colorChangeMinutesEnd);

  if(d.getHours() > colorChangeBegin.getHours() && d.getHours() < colorChangeEnd.getHours()) {
    document.getElementById("relogio").style.color = '#f00';
  }else {
    document.getElementById("relogio").style.color = '#0f0';
  }

  document.getElementById("relogio").innerHTML = displayDate;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente o relógio não esta aparecendo.

Comment: O código HTML está a funcionar? Eu testei esse código e aparecia-me o relógio da maneira certa http://prntscr.com/sfngvl